# Mysql - selecting rows with specific difference in timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have this Log table:

```
ID | controllerID | alert  | value | timestamp
1       1            ping      5         11:43:20
2       3            ping      4       11:45:21
3       1            low      3        11:46:25
4       1            ping     7        11:43:27
5       1            ping      12      11:44:29
6       1            ping       5656  11:45:28
7       1            ping       56     11:46:02
8       1            low       64      11:46:45
9       1            ping       6      11:48:02
```

I am looking for a specific controller and a specific type of alert:

```
WHERE controllerID = 1 and alert = 'ping'
```

And I need to output all the rows that the difference between their timestamps is more than a minute and there was no other 'ping' alert between them. So my output will be rows 4 and 5

```
ID | controllerID | alert  | value | timestamp
4       1            ping     7        11:43:27
5       1            ping      12        11:44:29
7       1            ping       56     11:46:02
9       1            ping       6      11:48:02
```

How can i implement it? It can be in 2 or more queries but only in MySQL.
I thought of ordering them by timestamp after sorting all the neccessary rows and then adding a new column to have a timedifference and selecting all that have more than a minute but i am not sure how i can add this new column.

Comment: `difference between their timestamps` your table have one timestamp right? what about another. `WHERE controllerID = 3 and alert = 'ping'` you specify `controllerID = 3` the result have `1`?

Comment: I mean difference between the timestamp for the row with ID=4 and ID=5. There are no ping alerts between them and their timestamps are more than 1 minute apart. About the controllers - sorry, my mistake, i meant controlelrID=1

Comment: Do you need this on a regularly basis (i.e. every 5 or 10 minutes) or just once a day or only if requested? How many rows will your table habe in a few days/weeks/months/years? Or old values removed after some time or do you need to have all history data results?

Comment: difference between two rows only ah? show samples with more records because if your have 6 row that also have timestamp difference between more than 1 mine of row 5 that you want get 4,5,6 rows ah

Comment: I will update the example. The table will be huge. It is a log table and for now nothing is get deleted. Off course i need to think when to delete when it is too old and remove to another archive. I will need to ask this query all the time (its a physical controller that checks that he was pinged by the browser and if not, there is a problem in a system). If you have other suggestions on how to implement it, i will be happy to hear

Comment: `timestamp` datatype ?

Comment: `AND DATEDIFF(minute, timestamp, timestamp)<=1` DATEDIFF is ur friend.

Comment: why first entry not comes in result

Comment: First entry shouldnt come in result because we have ping 4 that has a timestamp less than a minute from the first row